# I'm trying to call a method in a constructer every second for 15 seconds but setInterval doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, canvas

The code - also available [here](https://gist.github.com/SocketPhys/3cc53398a5941c9ea470#file-index-html):

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000" ;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
ctx.fillStyle ="#ffffff";

var entities = [];
var x;
var y;

function ship(x, y) {
  entities.push(entities.length-1);
  this.name = entities.length-1;
  this.draw = function(){
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,30,30);
  };

  this.update = function(){
    x+=10;
    this.draw();
  }; 
}

var bob = new ship(0,0);
bob.draw();

var intervalID = setInterval(bob.update(), 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}, 18000);
```

Basically, I draw a square on the top left corner. I then am trying to use a method to move it in real time. When I used a for loop, I can see that the square moved, but it obviously moves too fast to even notice.

Comment: You need to look at your setInterval call, [setInterval reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#Example)

Comment: Should be `bob.update` instead of `bob.update()`.

Comment: This is a totally reasonable question. For future reference,  I suspect the downvotes are because you didn't post the code in the question - posting an external link wrecks the future usefulness of the question if that link breaks. Have put in an edit request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a bound reference to bob.update

```
var intervalID = setInterval(bob.update.bind(bob), 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me why I needed to use .bind(). I thought that the "this" in update would be substituted with "bob" because I used bob.update.(After posting this, I changed the bob.update() to bob.update).

Comment: bob.update is just a function object - it has no knowledge of what `this` should refer to - `this` is purely a pointer to the current context. By binding the function to bob, you're declaring the context to be the bob object itself.

Comment: bob.update is just a reference to the "update" function on the "bob" object, It's not bob's function, so when it's called "this" has the wrong context. Bind creates a new function with its context set to bob.

Comment: You should add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change line 48 in index.html to

```
 var intervalID = setInterval(function(){bob.update()}, 1000);
```

and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I've not run the code, but this looks to be your problem

```
setInterval(bob.update(), 1000)
```

The first argument of `setInterval` needs to be a function object - in this case, the `update` function of the ship object.

In the above statement, you are actually *calling* the `update` function, so what's being passed to `setInterval` is not the `update` function itself, but the returned value from calling it - which is **undefined** - so your `setInterval` does.. nothing, each second.

You'll need to 'bind' the update function to the bob object, so that the value of `this` when it is actually invoked on each interval is the `this` of the bob object.

Change it to this, i.e. passing the `update` function bound to the bob object, and try running it again

```
setInterval(bob.update.bind(bob), 1000)
```

Comment: The bob.update function needs to be bound: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30744055/3259285